# How to install Qt 3.3.8 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu-14.04

Just recently I have begun to review the code for a project produced by a friend roughly 4 years ago. However, to compile this project I need an outdated version of `Qt (version 3.3.8)`. Much of the code used in this project isn't supported in the same style as `Qt4`. So I'd first like to obtain `Qt3` before I transition to `Qt4`.

Ubuntu has decided to no longer carry `"qt3-dev-tools"`. Ubuntu has limited the selection to `"qt4-dev-tools"` in its repository. So installing via the command line option (`sudo apt-get install qt3-dev-tools`) results in an error:

> "Unable to locate package qt3-dev-tools."

So, from here I did some digging for a manual installation? I found a great website to help me through the process, but I'm not very knowledgeable about Ubuntu, or Linux in general. Step 1 was simple. But step 2 and onward stumped me. I'm supposed to be both adding the environment variables listed in step two to the `.profile` file and then setting them, correct?

In step 2, is logging in again just meant for users with the `.login` shell? When I type in `$HOME/.qt-license` of step three, I suppose I'm typing this into the terminal?. Same with the `./configure`? Both of these commands return no such file exists.

Does anyone know a better walk through to install `Qt3` files, or can give a quick breakdown of this tutorial?

The website tutorial:
http://krm.am.gdynia.pl/doc/qt-3.3.8/INSTALL

Comment: Perhaps you could divulge what "this tutorial" on "a great website" is?

Comment: I have updated my post! Sorry!

Comment: I understand that you got stuck - that's not a "tutorial", that's the installation instructions for Qt3 (you should find exactly the same file in the sources you downloaded) and assumes that you're already familiar with source installation on Linux. You can use other repositories than the default - I would recommend looking for one that carries the version you want.

Answer (score 1):

If u can get .rpm  package then open it in ubuntu software centre . It will get installed.

Answer (score 1):

http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/3/ try downloading the package for qt3 from this qt archive & install it.